# formatting result output string

Tags: java

The following code provides the right output but not exactly in the same format that i need it in.

**Current code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Card C;

    System.out.println(deck.getTotalCards());
    System.out.print("Number of players: ");
    int players = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Number of cards: ");
    int cards = scan.nextInt();

    for(int k=0; k<players; ++k)
    {
        for(int i =0; i<cards; i++)
        {
            C = deck.drawFromDeck();
            System.out.println("Player "+(k+1) + ": " + C.toString());
        }
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

**This provides this output:**

```
51 // number of cards in deck

Number of players: 3 //3 - entered by user
Number of cards: 2 // 2- entered by user
Player 1: 4 of Spades
Player 1: Jack of Diamonds
Player 2: 6 of Clubs
Player 2: 2 of Hearts
Player 3: Jack of Clubs
Player 3: 8 of Diamonds
```

**Desired output:**

```
51
Number of players: 3 //3 - entered by user
Number of cards: 2 // 2- entered by user
Player 1: 4 of Spades, Jack of Diamonds
Player 2: 6 of Clubs, 2 of Hearts
Player 3: Jack of Clubs, 8 of Diamonds
```

How can i alter my for-loop to reflect my desired output.

Comment: If you're allowed to use arrays, then use two-dimensional array where row # n will hold all the cards of Player # n. Then use this array to print result. So you use your original nested loop to store the results and then create an additional one to print them out.

Comment: If the output is the only thing needed to be formatted, just mess around with `print` and `println`

Comment: @A--C that won't work because `print` will output all results for all players just for `Player 1`

Comment: @PM77-1 how can i implement this with my code. So i store the results from the first loop and then store results from second loop then combine both?

Comment: @Amina - Actually you do not need two-dimensional array. You can use one-dimensional just for a single player. Or you do not have to use arrays at all. Just follow the logic already suggested in posted answers: print "Player" in outer loop and "cards" in inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is save the output for each player in a String, and then print it outside the inner loop. So something like:

```
for(int k=0; k<players; ++k)
    {
        String output = " ";
        for(int i =0; i<cards; i++)
        {
            C = deck.drawFromDeck();
            output+= C.toString() + ",";
        }
        System.out.print("Player " + (k+1) + ": ");
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use System.out.print() instead of System.out.println() if you don't want a new line to be printed automatically. I think something like this would do it:

```
for(int k=0; k<players; ++k)
{
    System.out.print("Player "+(k+1) + ": ");
    for(int i =0; i<cards; i++)
    {
        C = deck.drawFromDeck();
        System.out.print(C.toString());
        if(cards >= 2 && i != cards - 2) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the inner loop, use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`. At the end of the outer loop, call `System.out.println()` to start the next output on the next line.

For example:

```
for (int k = 0; k < players; k++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < cards; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      System.out.print("Player "+(k+1) + ": ");
    }
    else {
      System.out.print(",");
    }
    C = deck.drawFromDeck();
    System.out.print(C.toString());
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```